# Is there a way to skip a stage in travis ci based on environment variables

Tags: travis-ci

We are using stages to deploy and run our different kinds of regression tests in parallel using stages. Is there a way I can skip certain scripts within stages based on an environment variable that is available when the travis job kicks off.

I read the travis-ci documentation and SO questions and this is the best I could come up with. This is a snippet of our current setup.

```
jobs:
  include:
  - stage: Setup
    script:
      - reset_db
      - reset_es_index
    name: Setting up Environment
    if: type IN (push, api)

  - stage: Tests
    script:
      - run_fast
    name: Fast tests
    if: type IN (push, api)
    allow_failure: true

  - script:
      - run_api_tests
    name: Api tests
    if: type = api AND env(TRIGGER_REPO) != com_ui_project

  - script:
      - run_slow_tests
    name: Slow tests
    if: type = api AND env(TRIGGER_REPO) != com_ui_project
```

As you can see I want to run the `Api tests` and the `Slow tests` scripts in the Test stage only if the travis job was triggered by an API call AND the custom environment variable is NOT `com_ui_project`. Otherwise run the `Fast tests` script and skip the other scripts.

Right now if the travis was triggered by the api call, all the scripts in the stage `Tests` run. How can I avoid that?

I tried the following too
`$TRIGGER_REPO != com_ui_project`
`env(TRIGGER_REPO) != "com_ui_project"`
`$TRIGGER_REPO!="com_ui_project"` (Thinking that using shell formatting might help. It did not)